libavcodec/avcodec.h file not found on macos-14 arm m1
I am writing a program that links to the ffmpeg dev libs and everything works correctly on ubuntu-22-x86-64 ubuntu-24-x86-64 macos-13-x86-64 but not on macos-14-arm-m1.
I install ffmpeg with brew install ffmpeg and then I run this command:
cc -fPIC -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/erlang/26.2.5/lib/erlang/erts-14.2.5/include -Ic_src/xav -shared  -undefined dynamic_lookup c_src/xav/xav_nif.c c_src/xav/reader.c c_src/xav/decoder.c c_src/xav/utils.c -o /Users/runner/work/xav/xav/_build/test/lib/xav/priv/libxav.so -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavformat -lavdevice -lswresample

which results in
In file included from c_src/xav/xav_nif.c:1:
c_src/xav/decoder.h:1:10: fatal error: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from c_src/xav/reader.c:1:
c_src/xav/reader.h:1:10: fatal error: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from c_src/xav/decoder.c:1:
c_src/xav/decoder.h:1:10: fatal error: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from c_src/xav/utils.c:1:
c_src/xav/utils.h:2:10: fatal error: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

When I locate header files and dynamic libs and set C_INCLUDE_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc., the compilation works but I assume that this shouldn't be needed, should it?
My understanding is that, if I install ffmpeg using some package manager, ffmpeg header files and .dylib or .so should be automatically searchable (as long as there is no bug in package manager's install script). Is that correct?
The same commands work on macos-13-intel-x86-64

No, your assumption about automatic searchability is not correct.

I mean, isn't this package maintainer responsibility to write a script that will install given library in a location that is included in compiler/linker's default search paths?

You are not using any package manager or similar stuff when you build your code, like cmake, which would do what you need, but again, no, package manager should not mess with compiler defaults.

I don't mean that package manager should mess with compiler defaults. I mean, it should put .so files in a path that compiler or linker use. E.g. install script for Alpine sets custom prefix https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/community/ffmpeg/APKBUILD#n211

Your problem is with header files, not with library files.

You can run on Macos/Intel:
ls -ld /usr/local/include/libavcodec
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  41 16 Jul 23:42 /usr/local/include/libavcodec -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0.1/include/libavcodec

But /usr/local/include/libavcodec does not exist after running brew install ffmpeg on Macos/m1

Is this correct that on ARM there is no link from /usr/local/include to brew's installation directory?

@mikeProgrammer That is correct according to my test. Do you see a link from /usr/local/include to brew's installation directory on your MacOS/ARM?

You can create that link to see if you still have to use C_INCLUDE_PATH.

Actually, I solved my problem by using pkg-config to find include and lib dirs when compiling on macos arm

@mikeProgrammer I'm curious to know if you have /usr/local/include/libavcodec on MacOS/ARM?
